# How is toEqual() in jest interpreted for immutable objects?

Tags: jestjs, immutable.js

I'm expecting both of these `toEqual()` tests to pass. The first one passes, but the second one doesn't. Why?

```
test('something', () => {
  const m = Map({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  })

  expect(m.valueSeq()).toEqual(m.valueSeq());
  expect(m.valueSeq().filter(_ => true)).toEqual(m.valueSeq());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```js
expect(m.valueSeq().filter(_ => true)).toEqual(m.valueSeq());
```

...calls `toEqual` [which calls `equal`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/5cde98eff6b8feba7f394f9e7f88cd8790d3ddad/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L526) passing it `iterableEquality` as a custom matcher:

```js
const pass = equals(received, expected, [iterableEquality]);
```

`iterableEquality` ends up returning `false` on [this line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/5cde98eff6b8feba7f394f9e7f88cd8790d3ddad/packages/expect/src/utils.ts#L157-L159):

```js
if (a.constructor !== b.constructor) {
  return false;
}
```

...because the constructors aren't equal:

```js
const { Map } = require('immutable');

test('something', () => {
  const m = Map({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  })

  const seq = m.valueSeq();
  const filter = m.valueSeq().filter(_ => true);

  console.log(seq.constructor);  // [Function: ToIndexedSequence]
  console.log(filter.constructor);  // [Function: IndexedCollection]

  expect(seq.constructor).not.toBe(filter.constructor); // Success! (different constructors)
});
```